# Column name id not found con SQL en JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Al ejecutar una consulta SQL como una `nativeQuery` en un entorno que utiliza `Spring` con JPA y `PostgreSQL` me devuelve error.

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
        select carga_termica.fecha, sum(carga_termica.carga_interna) as carga_interna, 
    sum(carga_termica.ganancia_solar) as ganancia_solar, sum(carga_termica.ground) as ground, 
    sum(carga_termica.muros) as muros, sum(carga_termica.particiones) as particiones, sum(carga_termica.qs) as qs, 
    sum(carga_termica.requerimiento_energetico_total) as requerimiento_energetico_total, 
    sum(carga_termica.techos) as techos, sum(carga_termica.ventanas) as ventanas, sum(carga_termica.ventilacion) as ventilacion
    from carga_termica
    inner join espacios
    on espacios.id=carga_termica.esp_id
    inner join edificios
    on edificios.id=espacios.edif_id
    where calibracion = true 
    and edificios.id=1
    and fecha >= '2018-10-08' and fecha <= '2018-10-14'
    group by fecha
    order by fecha ASC
```

Y el error es:

```sql
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2593) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2489) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner la consulta en su contexto spring, es decir, como la defines en spring? Me parece que estas poniendo la sentencia ya armada.

Comment: Hola Cristian, Bienvenido! Quizá teniendo la estructura de la base de datos implicada en la consulta (o las tablas usadas en la consulta) sería más fácil obtener respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: Las tablas implicadas son 3, edificios, carga_termica y espacios, respecto a lo que indica Juan, no te entendí a lo que te refieres con colocarla en su contexto Spring, Slds y muchas gracias desde ya

Comment: @Query("SELECT ct FROM CargaTermica ct WHERE ct.espacio.id = ?1 AND ct.calibracion = TRUE AND ct.fecha >= ?2 AND ct.fecha <= ?3 ORDER BY ct.fecha")
 public List<CargaTermica> findAllCalibracionByFechas(LocalDateTime fInicio, LocalDateTime fFin);

Comment: Esa es la query tipo spring, retorna como valor un objeto de tipo CargaTermica